# Копирование текста из input

Tags: javascript

Необходимо захватить текст из input и вставить его в span.
Ранее использовал функцию

```js
$(function(){
    var $foo = $('#foo');
    var $bar = $('#bar');
    function onChange() {
        $bar.val($foo.val());
    };
    $('#foo')
        .change(onChange)
        .keyup(onChange);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="foo" />
<input id="bar" />
```

Но это работает только для вставки в input.
Как взять значение из `<input id="foo" />` и вставить его в `<span id="bar"></span>` ?
При этом копирование должно быть моментальным сразу после ввода символа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var $foo = $('#foo');
  var $bar = $('#bar');

  function onChange() {
    $bar.text($foo.val());
  };
  $('#foo')
    .change(onChange)
    .keyup(onChange);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="foo" />
<span id="bar"></span>
```